# scala - access values from Option[List[Map[String,String]]]

Tags: scala

I am trying to parse the json string value.

```
val schema = "{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":false,\"metadata\":{}}]}"

val jsonMap = JSON.parseFull(schema).getOrElse(0).asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
val fields = jsonMap.get("fields")
val temp = fields.map(_.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]])
temp.foreach(_.get("name"))
```

**error**

```
<console>:29: error: value get is not a member of List[Map[String,String]]
       temp.foreach(_.get("name"))
                      ^
```

I need a map to be created from above json that has following values 
map("name"->"type") for each value in fields.

```
Map("name"->"String", "age"->"integer")
```

Comment: @user it returns empty list.

Comment: Probably you wanted `temp.flatten.foreach(_.get("name"))`

Comment: @Duelist getting compile time error

Comment: What compile error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp` is an `Option`. You can use this style to get the value if available. Posting the full sample code file.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
object Test extends App {
  val schema = "{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"integer\",\"nullable\":false,\"metadata\":{}}]}"
  val jsonMap = JSON.parseFull(schema).getOrElse(0).asInstanceOf[Map[String,Any]]
  val fields = jsonMap.get("fields")
  val temp = fields.map(_.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]])
  val result = temp match {
    case Some(x) => x.foldLeft(Map[String, String]()) { (map, entry) => map + (entry("name") -> entry("type"))}
    case None => throw new Exception("Error")
  }
  print(result)
}
```

**Result**

```
Map(name -> string, age -> integer)
```

Comment: it returned, empty list

Comment: @GaurangShah I updated the code address your question update of getting the name -> type mapping.

Comment: Can't even compile the new version `Error:(34, 87) (String, Any) does not take parameters
      case Some(x) => x.foldLeft(Map[String, String]()) { (map, entry) => map + (entry("name") -> entry("type"))}`